# unable to open cloudera vm in vmware from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: vmware, ubuntu-16.04

installed Ubuntu 16,
currently trying to use vmware to open cloud-era vm.. as soon as power on is hit.. vmware shuts down. is there settings gone missing.
Until now i have only unbundled the vmware and using it.
there are no additional changes done by me.

Comment: This type of question is not appropriate for StackOverflow. Please take some time to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so you can learn what types of questions are accepted here, how to write questions, and how to use this site effectively. Try asking them in superuser/askubuntu.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is nothing in it to do programming.